# How do I create an HTML template that I can copy dynamically?

Tags: javascript

What's the correct way to do the (pseudo) following:

```
<div id="myTemplate">
  <div id="child1"></div>
  <span id="child2"></span>
</div>


<script>
  var templateCopy = document.getElementById("myTemplate")
  var copy1 = document.createElementFromTemplate(templateCopy);
  document.appendChild(copy1);
</script>
```

TIA

Comment: I would look at a framework or library. jQuery has templates: http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/

Comment: Why? Why not use a templating engine? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: templating engine? to perform a simple function? Seems like overkill. Anyway... I think cloneNode is the function I'm looking for... double checking now...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WXgrM/1/ this is an example that I found several days ago somewhere here.

Comment: You shouldn't use id's in a template.  When it is copied, you'll have a duplicate id.

Comment: If you only need it for a simple usage, you could use a simple function that returned your needed markup for appending. It doesn't have to be complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var copy1 = templateCopy.cloneNode(true)`, beware - id will be copied too.

Comment: yeah, that's what I'm looking for... thanks very much.  I can change the id, I believe.  I'm a little surprised how many jQuery answers I'm getting for something so straight forward... I have no use or need for jQuery. I'm performing a simple task, I don't want to load a giant framework to accomplish it!

Answer (score 0):

I know you can do it in jQuery http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has contributed a jQuery by having jQuery Templates plugin. Hope this helps

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl

Answer (score 0):

jQuery templates do pretty much what you are asking. You can use

```
  $("elem").tmpl(output)
```

... And also have string substitutions too.